# What is the value of this Gamma type integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I am wondering the value of the following integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t(1+t)}} dt.$$
It seems like $\Gamma(1/2)$ but the integrand has an extra term $1/\sqrt{1+t}$ which makes the integral complicated.

Comment: CAS gives $\sqrt{e}K_0(\frac 12)$, but I'm not familiar with Bessel K function. Maybe try to find an integral representation of it (edit I found this https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) and substitute to get there, maybe...

Comment: Making the substitution $t=s-\frac{1}{2}$
$$I=\int_{1/2}^\infty\frac{e^{-(s-1/2)}}{\sqrt{(s-1/2)(s+1/2)}}ds=\sqrt e\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$
Making another substitution $x=\cosh t$
$$I=\sqrt e\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cosh t}dt=\sqrt eK_0\big(1/2)$$ https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E9